# Calorie Calculator with Drupal: There are modules or solutions?

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

I want to create a calorie calculator with Drupal 7. You should be able to choose different foods and at the end the total calories should be calculated. Are there solutions (modules) - does anyone know the best solution? Is it possible with [Webform Calculator](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_calculator)?

Comment: There is some dev code in the sandbox placed here: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/web247/1093298. At a first glance webform calculator should do what you request.

Comment: Will you be happy to do some php coding? If yes, I can tell you how to implement the structure and where to put the custom code.

Comment: Before one might be able to answer this question, I think you should enhance (edit) your question to explain where the input for your calculations is coming from. Like how much calories is a salade, a waffle, etc. Maybe from nodes or entities in your site? From some external database? A webservice? User input via a form?